# Passing Host IP address into cmd.run and ini files

Tags: salt-stack

I am currently trying to deploy Log-rhythm out into our environment that consists of 100+ Servers with the help of SaltStack:

While I am able to copy files over to a Windows minion with the use of file.managed, I am facing some difficulty in the process getting the IP Address of the minion server and adding this both to the .ini file and cmd.run file. 
I would like to be able to do this for each minion that is connected to Salt:

While running salt -G 'roles:logging' state.apply. I seem to be getting the following error:
Rendering SLS 'base:pacakage-logrhythm' failed: Jinja variable 'dict object' has no attribute 'fqdn_ip4':

UPDATE:

I was able to resolve the issue within the ini files: by placing the following 
ClientAddress={{ grains['fqdn_ip4'][0] }}

currently having issues with passing grains into the cmd.run section of the program:

```
create_dir:
  file.directory:
    - name: C:\logrhythm

/srv/salt/logrhythm/proxy1.ini:
  file.managed:
    - source: salt://logrhythm/proxy1.ini
    - name: c:\logrhythm\proxy1.ini
    - template: jinja

/srv/salt/logrhythm/proxy2.ini:
  file.managed:
    - source: salt://logrhythm/proxy2.ini
    - name: c:\logrhythm\proxy2.ini
    - tempalte: jinja

LRS_File:
  file.managed:
    - name: c:\logrhythm\LRSystemMonitor_64_7.4.2.8003.exe
    - source: salt://logrhythm/LRSystemMonitor_64_7.4.2.8003.exe

LRS_Install:
  cmd.run:
    - name: 'LRSystemMonitor_64_7.4.2.8003.exe /s /v" /qn ADDLOCAL=System_Monitor,RT_FIM_Driver HOST=<> SERVERPORT=443 CLIENTADDRESS={{ grains[''fqdn_ip4''][0] }} CLIENTPORT=0"'
    - cwd: C:\logrhythm
```

Comment: Client address can = 0 and it will use the OS NIC binding order to assign an IP to the local system monitor.  I usually push out agents and only set the data processor host IP and leave the client port and IP as 0.  LR recommends that.

Answer (score 0):

I think it should work. You may have a problem with the multiple quotes you use: simple then double then simple. Trying removing the simple quotes englobing all the command and the two simple for accessing the grains dict.

```
    - name: LRSystemMonitor_64_7.4.2.8003.exe /s /v" /qn ADDLOCAL=System_Monitor,RT_FIM_Driver HOST=<> SERVERPORT=443 CLIENTADDRESS={{ grains['fqdn_ip4'][0] }} CLIENTPORT=0"
```